# iPhone: how to work with augmented reality

Tags: iphone, camera, overlay, augmented-reality

In augmented reality app,on Camera view another transparent view will be, On this transparent view, we used for drawing on camera view and saving it, can you suggest (Start and end) me how to work with this application, 
thanks you, have a great day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use a UIImagePickerController to show the camera preview. Set its showsCameraControls property to no, so none of the standard photo-taking interface is visible.  Now, UIImagePickerControllers have a nice little cameraOverlayView property that you can use to place any view you want over the camera preview. Depending on what precisely you want to augment your reality with, this view could be realized in different ways. For example, if you want to overlay 3D models over the camera preview, this view could be a transparent OpenGL ES context. If you don't need any 3D assets, it can be a regular transparent UIView on which you draw some custom graphics with Quartz. It's up to you, but you want the general pattern of:

- UIImagePickerController with showsCameraControls = NO
- set cameraOverlayView to some transparent view to render content

This is really a huge question, and there are tons of intricacies depending on the specifics of your design. This is just a general summary.

Comment: hi Matt Wilding, thank you for suggestion and i got small problem in Augmentation Reality app for that i need answer from you, on camera view we placed another transparent view for drawing on camera view and taking screen shot to save both view, after pressing the button screen shot take place, in screen shot image is saving with button, but it have to save only camera and transparent views only, did i want to approch in another way to solve this problem or can you suggest me with other method to this problem, thank you, have a Nice Day

Comment: Do you have code for how you're currently taking this screenshot? It's hard to suggest blind. One thing I could think of of the top of my head would be to set that button's hidden property to YES, or its alpha to 0.0f immediately before capturing the screen.

Comment: Thank you i will try and inform it to you

Comment: Hi Matt wilding,i am thinking to implement NSTimer to take screen shot after hidding the UIButton,can you tell me how to implement this with EXAMPLE.

Comment: I woud need to know the context. Why do you want to use a timer to trigger the screenshot? Do you want to take the screenshot after a set delay, or take it repeatedly? Why not just hide it and then immediately take it?

Comment: hi Matt Wilding because i am developing Augmentation reality app, when camera rolling in iPhone, we can draw on it and save in album use screen shot, this screen shot take with UIButton action, i am saving with UIButton also, so i dont want to save with UIButton